# what is the preg_match solution in php for matching anything between '[' and ']'?

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot of strings which have characters like

```
[anything]
```

where the word

```
anything == any kind of characters, such as ~!@#$%^&*()
```

what will be the `preg_match()` code for matching such string in PHP?

Comment: Some RegEx like `/\[[^\]]+\]/` will do the work. However, if your string has something like `[foo[bar]]`, it (and any other RegEx) will not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[(.+?)\]/s', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

That will loop through all the times text between brackets was found in your string.